# Regular Expressions, Remove all punctuation except () -

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been trying to use a regular expression to remove all instances of any punctuation except () - and . from a string but finding it pretty difficult to get my head around.

This is the one i have came up with but it does do everything i need it do.

Has anyone got any suggestions or help?? Any would be much appreciated

```
Regex.Replace(address, @"(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9])(?!/s\*)", "");
```

Comment: How are you defining punctuation? Is this a multinational solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Regex.Replace(address, @"[\p{P}-[()\-.]]", "");
```

Little explanation: \p{P} or \p{Punctuation} matches any kind of punctuation character ([see unicode categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html))

Comment: I think you need `.` and `-` in the subtraction class, but other than that I *like* this regex.

Comment: This has worked how i needed it too, also helped me figure out where i was going wrong before thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following regex may meet your needs:

```
Regex.Replace(address, @"[^\w\s\-\.\(\)]")
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

What about use `char.IsPunctuation` method like this:

```
var newString = new string(yourString.Where(x => !char.IsPunctuation(x) || x == '(' || x == ')' || x == '.'))
```

Comment: he want a regular expressioin

Comment: I thought he found it too difficult, so why not to try this?

Comment: @Julie that's because he lack the experience to know which tools to use. It's like using a spanner when a ratchet would make the task easier and simpler.

Comment: sometimes OP whould understand the reasons  and not a work around